# Why is the PHP Zend Framework coding style inconsistent with respect to brace alignment?

Tags: php, zend-framework, coding-style

In the PHP Zend Framework coding style:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html

The style for classes and functions is like the Microsoft style - brace aligned, while the style for control statements such as if and switch is K&R - brace offset.

Can anyone offer a rationale for why the two distinct styles are used within the same standard?

Comment: What do you expect as answer? No coding style has any other rational reason, than to "force" a consistent style within the project. The zf maintainers decided to use this style, thats all. I dont think its worth to think about ;)

Comment: I think this coding style is adopted from the c++ coding style. It's a little bit old fashion but still very nice IMO.

Comment: Might just as well be [PEAR inspired](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php). They do it like that, too. Consider asking on a ZF mailing list if you want to know for sure.

Comment: @KingCrunch: If you really think that way, you should read David Straker's book on the subject. It is a subject that can be treated seriously, and scientifically, with a little work. http://syque.com/cstyle/index.htm

Comment: @Gordon has it. The ZF coding standards are based on those of PEAR with some modifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matthew Weier O'Phinney answers it best at: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/ZF-Coding-Guidelines-td656845.html

> In large part, our standards are
>   adopted from PEAR coding standards
>   (which in turn were adopted from Horde
>   CS); our goal is to have standards
>   that are interchangeable with other
>   projects, to ensure code consistency
>   and readability. PEAR standards are
>   widely adopted (ADODb, Solar, Phing,
>   and others all use PEAR CS), and are a
>   logical choice.
>
> If you want to know why 1TB is used as
>   it is, I suggest looking at the list
>   archives for the PEAR and Horde
>   projects.

Discussion of the coding standards: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Coding-Standards-amp-ZF-0-2-td638409.html